# Is there a barcode app that works on pictures instead of needing to be connected to wifi for it to work?

Tags: ios, applications, wifi, scanning

I've got a couple of barcode apps, but they all require that you have the item, the camera, and the internet connection at the same place.

Are there any barcode apps where you can take a picture of the item's barcode, store the picture, and then feed it into the app when you have an internet connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [RedLaser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/redlaser/id312720263?mt=8) and it has this capability. If RedLaser can't connect to the internet when you take the picture of the barcode, it will store the number and let you look it up later:

[image]

Comment: @leeand00 glad I could help!